# How are URLs mapped to their respective IP addresses in DNS?

Tags: networking, dns, tld, nslookup, sld

What would be an explanation to a site being mapped to its IP address in DNS? I know inverse tree / resolver and name server are part of the process, but what are the actual steps?

Answer (score 0):

They are not. The DNS does not deal with URL, which is a concept at level 4 of the Internet stack, that is the application protocol part, like HTTP here.

In the DNS you find domain names, host names, and IP addresses (both v4 and v6).

The browser extracts the hostname from the URL, resolves it to some IP, connects to it, if under HTTPS sends the hostname in SNI extension during TLS handshake, and then send the URL inside its first HTTP message, typically in part using the `host` header.

There is an `URL` record type in the DNS, but it is rarely used. In theory `SRV` records could also be used by browsers to find the proper server to connect to based on the hostname in the URL, but in practice browsers do not use it for various technical and non technical reasons.